# Agrupar consulta sin perder registros distintos

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito ayuda realizar la siguiente consulta:

[image: Tabla]

Desde la tabla permisos obtener fila del usuario sin perder datos de la columna acción y valor.

Saludos,.

Comment: lo que quieres es pivotar la tabla? si no tenemos mas información es difícil ayudarte. por ejemplo por que ventas va a accion1 y no a accion 2, o a accion 3 ...

Comment: por favor @sebamim dos cosas que nos ayudarían a orientarte en lo solución sería el detalle de tu problema,  algo de código que hayas avanzado y un ejemplo de como te gustaría finalmente que quedara el resultado de la consulta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estimado, el select seria de esta forma:

```
 select usuario, modulo, accion  as accion1, valor, 
 (select a.accion from test.permisos a where a.usuario=t.usuario limit 1,1 ) as accion2 ,
 (select b.valor from test.permisos b where b.usuario=t.usuario limit 1,1  ) as valor2 
 from test.permisos t group by usuario
```

cree una tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]