# Agrupar consulta sin perder registros distintos 2

Tags: mysql

Hola yo tengo el mismo problema que en esta pregunta ([Agrupar consulta sin perder registros distintos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/171056/42381)), es complicado explicarlo.

Cuando se agrupan los resultados de los registros, se pierde información, por ejemplo tengo datos en la tabla de clientes y en la tabla de ventas, necesito saber en que fecha se le realizó la venta a dicho cliente, entonces si quiero sumar las ventas por cada cliente se usaria `group by ventas.id_cliente`, pero en ese agrupamiento se pierden las fechas porque son por venta, al agrupar por `ventas.id_venta` entonces si se visualizan las fechas que necesito saber pero lo que realmente necesito es que al agruparlo por `ventas.id_cliente`, en termino de 30 días si ese cliente compró algo, luego en termino de 60 dias las ventas de ese cliente y en 90 días las ventas de ese cliente, agrupado por `ventas.id_cliente`, no puedo determinar si hubieron ventas hace 30 dias porque se pierde la fecha de las ventas de hace 30 dias en el agrupamiento por `id_cliente`. Entonces la pregunta es, cómo evitar que se pierdan esos datos?
PS: Ok, voy a tratar de explicarlo mejor: aquí pongo una imagen de las tablas agrupadas por id_venta
[image: Consulta de ventas x clientes agrupado por id_venta]

Son dos registros porque ese cliente tiene dos ventas, una venta en cada fecha respectivamente, los campos que se muestran con 0_30 se refiere a que si esa venta tiene 30 dias de antigüedad, el campo 30_60 si las ventas tienen 60 dias de antigüedad, y así sucesivamente. Pero cuando lo agrupo por clientes, desaparece el registro de la fecha mas actual y necesito que me la cuente para que el resultado sea así:
Esto es agrupado por id_cliente
[image: Consulta de ventas x clientes agrupado por id_cliente]

Pero lo que obtengo es esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso, es como si no tomara en cuenta el registro de la fecha más actual, al agruparse por id_cliente se pierde.

Comment: Vas a tener que explicarte mejor. Pega en tu pregunta un fragmento del contenido de tus dos tablas, y otro fragmento de cómo querrías que quedara

Comment: bro, debe por lo menos poner la consulta que tienes hasta ahora y tambien las  tablas que usas en BD

Comment: tendrias que usar un subquery parecido a la respuesta que mencionan en la pregunta que pusiste de referencia

Comment: Si agregas un ejemplo de datos podremos ayudarte mejor. mira por favor el [tour] y tambien  [ask]

Comment: Resulta complejo, son varias tablas, el campo que dice valorCobro es el abono que ese cliente hizo a esa factura, todas esas ventas fueron al crédito, por lo general todos los clientes se les asigna 30 dias de crédito para que termine de pagar lo que debe de esa factura, entonces el saldo debe ser la venta total - el valorCobro pero no puedo relacionar todas esas tablas, se complica demasiado, por lo tanto trato de hacerlo separado. pero de esa forma me enuentro con ese otro problema a la hora de agrupar por id_cliente

Comment: yo entiendo lo que vos queres, pero es dificil armar el query en el aire... si podes hacer un fiddle mejor... el query que necesitas no es trivial, pero se puede hacer...

Comment: lo que si, la fecha de venta no tiene nada que hacer en ese resultado.. no tiene ningun sentido...

Comment: Parecería que se podría resolver con un `GROUP_CONCAT`, pero la pregunta no se entiende, sobre todo la cuestión de los 30, los 60 o los 90 días. ¿Quizá convendría controlar esos criterios en el mismo `SELECT` usando funciones de fecha/período adecuadas? Sin entender el contexto es difícil dar una respuesta óptima.

Comment: @A.Cedano lo que yo entiendo que necesita es lo siguiente.. dada la fecha actual, contar la cantidad de dias desde la vta. dependiendo la fecha sumar en una columna distinta ese valor por registro, y despues agrupar por cliente. pero sin datos, asi en el aire, es bastante complicado hacer el query.. seguro que le pifio en algo...

Answer (score 0):

Contando el total de cada venta de ese cliente, por cada registro del select:

```
 select (select Count(id_cliente) 
              from ventas 
                  where ventas.id_cliente = v1.id_cliente
            ) _ventas_por_cliente 
         , v1.*
    from ventas v1
```

O Haciendo un inner join de la tabla ventas y de un select con los totales
    Siendo esta la que menos trabajo innecesario realice.

```
 select v2.*, v1.*
    from ventas v1 INNER JOIN (select Count(*) as _total,id_cliente
              from ventas 
                  group by id_cliente
            ) v2 ON v1.id_cliente = v2.id_cliente
```

Answer (score 0):

Voy a intentar darte una solución...

Necesitamos armar una tabla, que devuelva esos datos como vos queres.. y despues agrupar.. entonces vamos a hacer lo siguiente...

```
select 
id_venta,
id_cliente,
(CASE
    WHEN DATEDIFF(fechaventa,NOw()) < 31 THEN valorCobro
    else 0) as 0_30,
(CASE
    WHEN DATEDIFF(fechaventa,NOw()) between (31,60) THEN valorCobro
    else 0) as 31_60,
(CASE
    WHEN DATEDIFF(fechaventa,NOw()) between (61,90) THEN valorCobro
    else 0) as 61_90,
(CASE
    WHEN DATEDIFF(fechaventa,NOw()) > 90 THEN valorCobro
    else 0) as 90_mas,
from Tabla
```

Y luego, esta tabla podria ser la entrada de otra tabla que solo haga las sumas

```
select
     id_cliente,
     sum(0_30),
     sum(31_60),
     sum(61_90),
     sum(90_mas)
from 
    (la tabla anterior)
gropu by id_cliente
```

Comment: Si  exacto de hecho asi tengo la consulta, pero el problema es que cuando lo agrupo por id_cliente, mas de alguna fecha se pierde en el agrupamiento, y lo complejo es que necesito la suma del total de ventas, la suma del valorCobro de todas las ventas agupados por clientes mas sin embargo, necesito el saldo de cada unas de esas ventas sin agruparlo por id_clinete sino por id_venta por cada cliente, no he puesto la consulta por ser datos confidenciales y no me ha quedado tiempo de hacer una con datos falsos, pero por lo menos lo haré con dos registros.

Comment: y si tenias esta consulta, porque no la pusiste? y empezabamos a trabajar desde ahi? tambien deberias mirar [mcve]. No importan los datos, pero si el ejemplo. y entonces no se entiende nada de lo que necesitas. Mostra los datos, como queres que queden en la primer agrupacion y como queres que queden despues. Conseguiste dos respuestas que no son lo que necesitas porque no fuiste claro. tene en cuenta que la gente que se toma el trabajo de leer tu pregunta, necesita saber todo para no perder tiempo buscando una solucion que ya sabes. @Schismdark

Comment: Si tenes razón, agradezco mucho tus comentarios y respuesta, la proxima vez  lo haré mejor.